# Comparing 2 files and removing unwanted columns

Tags: python, dataframe, compare

I have a ref file and a raw data file. I have added all the headers of my raw data file to list_columns and all the headers of my ref file to wanted_header.

My raw data file is formatted like this:

```
Time        Title1   Title2  Title3 etc..
timestamp     34       43      49 
timestamp     23       54      23
etc.

output:
list_columns = ['Title1','Title2','Title3',etc.]
```

My ref file:

```
Title_Name  |    Zone   |  Description  |  Symbol
Title1      | lalala    | happy day     |pa2
Title3      | monkey    | pies          |Ja2
Title7      |lksadfjsad |salkdfjs       |aslkf
Title7      |lksadfjsad |salkdfjs       |aslkf

output:
wanted_header =
0    Title1
1    Title3
2    Title7
3    Title7
```

I want to compare the list_columns to wanted_headers and

1. remove the columns from list_columns that are not present in wanted_header except for time and print out ('header "blah" was not found in raw data file")
2. if there is a duplicate header in wanted_headers, I want to abort the calculations and print ('header "blah" was found x times in ref file')
3. match the zone, description, and symbol information to the correct title in the raw data file

```
example answer:
header Title2 was not found in raw data file
header Title7 was found 2 times in ref file


                                (delete)
                                (column)
Time                Title1       Title2      Title3 etc..
timestamp             34           43          49 
timestamp             23           54          23
etc.
zone                lalala                    monkey
description        happy day                  pies 
symbol                pa2                     Ja2
```

How can I do this ? I would like to have dataset to have the wanted titles and added data.

This is what I have so far:

```
dataset = {}

"""list of columns headers"""
df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8').fillna(0)
list_columns = df.columns.values.tolist() 

"""database headers"""
want=pd.read_csv(filename2,sep="|").fillna(0)
wanted_header = want.loc[:,'filename2'].str.strip()

# creates an empty index of which columns in the raw data have the wanted headers
wanted_columns=[-2 for a in range(len(wanted_header))]

for i in range(0,len(wanted_header)):
    wanted_columns[i]=list_columns.index(wanted_header[i])

#holds corrected dataframe
for col in wanted_columns:
    dataset[col] = df[col].iloc[0:].values
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to slim down the columns based on the headers of the ref file? In this case, you could filter down the data frame after deciding which columns to keep.

For example:

```
list_columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] #or raw.columns
wanted_headers = ['a', 'c', 'c', 'e'] #or ref.columns

wanted_columns = []

for col in list_columns:
    if col not in wanted_headers:
        print("Header {0} not found in raw data file".format(col))
    elif wanted_headers.count(col) > 1:
        print("Header {0} found {1} times in ref file".format(col, 
        wanted_headers.count(col)))
        #wanted_columns.append(col)
        break
    else:
        wanted_columns.append(col)
```

The results if you took out the duplicate 'c' would be ['a', 'c', 'e']. Then you could use a dataframe command to get the subset.

```
df = df[wanted_columns]
```

Comment: Is there a way to know the location of the headers wanted? Also, my wanted_headers is in a list format (0 a, 1 b, 2 c) while my list_columns is in an array format ['a','b','c']. The program is having issues comparing the two...

Comment: There's definitely a way, here's a [sample article](https://datagy.io/python-list-find-all-index/#:~:text=One%20of%20the%20most%20basic,both%20the%20index%20and%20element.) that goes into detail. Personally, I would use the numpy example, or a list comprehension rather than a for loop. @HoneyWeGOTissues

As for the type conversion, I take it you mean to convert a dict (a: 1, b: 2) to a list? If you're looking for just the keys (a, b) you can do 
`wanted_headers = wanted_headers.keys()`